# SSIS Parameters With Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, ssis, etl

I've done quite a bit of searching on this but haven't been able to come up with a solid solution.  I have a use case where for example I want to include the date in the file name, let's say I use the following formula:

```
"EmployeeCount_"+(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() )+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2)  + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2) +".csv"
```

This works out great as a variable, but what if I want to pass this function as a parameter from SSMS?  Is there a way for Parameters to be evaluated as a expression?  I attempted passing the parameter into a variable to achieve the desired effect to no available.

Am I missing something here, or should I just be hard coding this into a variable / calculating this elsewhere and pulling it into SSIS from a table?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the value from a database function and store in a variable you can use the Execute SQL Task.

You can combine variables with expressions in other variables along with scripts. Where you perform the calculation is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to create 2 variables `p_Date` of type `DateTime` and `Filename` of type `String`
2. In the properties tab set `EvaluateAsExpressions` = True for the variable `Filename` and Use the following expressions

   ```
   "EmployeeCount_"+(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , @[User::p_Date]  )+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" ,  @[User::p_Date]  ), 2)  + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" ,  @[User::p_Date] ), 2) +".csv"
   ```

[image]

[image]

3. Add an `Execute SQL Task`
4. Set `ResultSet`property to `Single Row`
5. Fill the `SqlCommand`  and `Connection` property

[image]

6. Go to `ResultSet` Tab , Add a New Result Set like shown in the image below

[image]

*Note: `0` in the image above means the index of column from the sql command your provided*